# Dividing a float and an Integer in SQL and getting a Integer result

Tags: sql

I am dividing a float value (such as 87.34234) by a Integer value (2) in SQL and I would like the resulting answer to be an integer with no decimal places.

Thanks

Comment: Then round it down (floor) ...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What's the expected result if you instead divide -4.56 by 2?

Comment: In some DBMS's, this is the default behavior.   What result do you get when you try?

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic answer, check if you are happy with this:

```
select cast(87.34234/2 as int)
```

or second option:

```
select cast(round(87.34234/2,0) as int)
```